# curl_close will clean up the return result of curl_exec

Tags: php, curl

I surely confirm the result of curl_exec will be cleaned up by curl_close.
I have to comment out the curl_close line to get the result.My php version is 5.3.8.
How do I get result with curl_close?
Here is my code

```
function curl_get_contents($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $r = curl_exec($ch);
    //curl_close($ch);
    return $r;
}
```

Comment: you're saying that if you uncomment //curl_close($ch); this code fails?

Comment: You don't need to do a curl close. PHP will clean up for you when the function returns and $ch goes out-of-scope.

Comment: @jlb Yes,I have to comment out this line.

Comment: To @MarcB: Thanks.If no solution I will leave this comment out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has no effect on the return value, as long as the data from `curl_exec();` is stored in `$r` you can return as you like.

This works normally.

```
function curl_get_contents($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $r = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $r;
 }

$returnedValue = curl_get_contents($url); //Holds the contents
```

Edit as Marc B pointed out :

> You don't need to do a curl close. PHP will clean up for you when the
>   function returns and $ch goes out-of-scope.

Hence there's no point of even closing it, but it shouldn't happen.

Comment: The problem on my xampp suit.My curl version:7.21.7